# How to skip Safari's "Do you want to allow this page to open X" dialog?

Tags: macos, safari

I'm pretty sure I haven't changed any setting or installed anything other than software updates, but today I've started getting this dialog when I clicked a magnet link:

[image]

How do I get rid of this dialog? I've clicked okay once, but then I've clicked another magnet link and got the same dialog again. Why did it suddenly start and how do I get rid of Safari constantly asking about it?

I'm on macOS 10.12.2/Safari 10.0.2

Comment: Same thing is now happening for me with Vuze - would love to be able to stop it.

Comment: Looks like macOS 10.12.2 Update caused this security setting in Safari.  I swapped to Firefox to avoid it for now.  Using spctl to sign Vuze didn't fix it.

Comment: I mean just once at the first time might be a good feature, but how is this even a "feature" when it repeatedly asks every time I use the same app on even the same site!

Comment: Same problem here. This seems to be a new security feature that doesn't have an obvious pref to turn it off, and the answer isn't "sticky": it asks every time. We use this feature internally to launch FileMaker (with an "fmp://" URL) for our users via a URL, so this is disruptive and we'd like to turn it off, at least for FileMaker.

Comment: @JohnEDee It may not help you but note that using the "open" command on the Terminal should work around this warning message:

open fmp://xxxxxx

Comment: The latest Safari Technology Preview is still affected by this issue for the record…

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Luc.  Unfortunately the URL is for our end-users to click in an email to open FileMaker, and there's no way to have that trigger an open command in Terminal.

Comment: It is a security setting. It is there because it wouldn't be hard to make a webpage that opens a lot of apps at the same time and crashes your computer. That's why it's there.

Comment: @JakubSrnka of course it's a security settings and IMO it's a good one. However, *constantly* asking *every time* after the first one decreases user experience.

Comment: Has there been any workaround added to Safari since this was asked?

Comment: @JakubSrnka I don't see that - unless you plan to click on every link on a webpage, nothing should launch.

Answer (score 4):

If the application you want to use is already running (or is in the dock), you can drag and drop the magnet link onto the application's dock icon to avoid the dialog.

There's also a [discussion](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=18205) on the Transmission forum on this. The dialog that appears when clicking on such a link seems to be a Safari security feature that currently can't be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Safari 17+

Safari 17 will let you **Always Allow** a website to open an app.

[image]

*Source:* A screenshot of Safari 17 Beta by [@ezekiel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/65767/ezekiel) in [How to open a Zoom link in a non-browser app without being prompted?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331348/how-to-open-a-zoom-link-in-a-non-browser-app-without-being-prompted/462939#462939). I was not able to confirm this feature in the [Safari 17 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-17-release-notes). Safari 17 was publicly released in Fall 2023 with this feature.

Answer (score -5):

I have a set of interactive displays to control my entertainment center via calls on iRed.  The change in Safari rendered these useless.  I tried to circumvent the warning dialog but finally gave up.  Until this warning can be avoided, I switched to the Vivaldi browser.  It works perfectly and I'm able to use my entertainment center again without a multitude of remotes.

Answer (score -6):

I was able to eliminate the message by treating it as an extension conflict.

1. Safari > Preferences: Extensions.
2. Disable all extensions and test.
3. Reenable extensions one at a time, retesting after each one.
4. Update or uninstall the conflicting extensions.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the same message as shown in the screenshot?  I'm seeing the message even with Extensions turned off, and it doesn't seem to be Extension-related anyway...it's a core part of Safari.  My guess is we'll need a "defaults write" way to turn this off, if such a setting for that exists.

Comment: My solution works for me.  With the Kablock! extension enabled, I get the annoying message in situations similar to the one you displayed.  With it disabled, I don't.  I lack the expertise to say more than that or speculate on why my experience might be idiosyncratic.

Comment: I see what you mean:  some Extensions can trigger the same message by trying to open apps themselves.  But this issue can happen without Extensions at all, simply by giving Safari a URL to open that the Mac associates with an application.  

An example is a "mailto:" link:  although the dialog that Safari pops up is a little different, it's the same issue.  For example, try a link like mailto:feedback@apple.com in Safari and it should trigger the dialog.  (I tried to create the link here in the comment, but can't get it to work).
We encountered it with using FileMaker links, i.e. "fmp://"

Comment: I have no extensions at all, so that's not the root issue.

Comment: I don't use any extensions at all.