# How to open a Zoom link in a non-browser app without being prompted?

Tags: safari, links

URLs have long been the domain of web browsers, but some apps challenge this assumption by asking your browser to open a link in their dedicated app.

### Problem: Safari Keeps Asking Permission

For example, I use Zoom.us, a videoconferencing service. They give me a link associated with my conference call that's easy to throw into a calendar invite, like `https://ibm.zoom.us/j/9747900418`. When I click the link, my browser opens it, authenticates me, and asks me permission to open the link in *zoom.us.app*, which I've already installed.

[image: Dialog asking to open a page in zoom.us]

> Click Allow on the dialog shown by your browser
> If you don't see a dialog, click Launch Meeting below
>
> Do you want to allow this page to open "zoom.us.app"?
> Cancel | Allow

After opening hundred of meetings this way, I'm sick of it asking me permission. I want Safari to remember that it's allowed to open `zoom.us/*` links in *zoom.us.app*.

### What I've Tried

Under Safari > Preferences > Websites, I escalated privileges for Zoom-related items:

- General > Auto-Play > ibm.zoom.us was "Stop media with sound"; set to "Allow Auto-Play"
- Plug-ins > Zoom Launcher 3.0.1 > ibm.zoom.us was "Ask"; set to "On"
- Plug-ins > Zoom Launcher 3.0.1 > support.zoom.us was "Ask"; set to "On"

This had no effect. So how can I get Zoom links to open correctly?

Answer (score 13):

**Sad 2022 update:**

Support for client URLs (e.g. the `zoommtg://` protocol)  [apparently has been deprecated](https://web.archive.org/web/20210909101438/https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/client-url-schemes).

If you have an older Zoom client, it likely supports `zoommtg://`; but for security reasons, it's not wise to continue using older versions.

**Original answer:**

Have you tried rewriting the URL so that it uses the [zoommtg:// protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919000816/https://medium.com/zoom-developer-blog/zoom-url-schemes-748b95fd9205)?

You rewrite a URL of this format ...

```
https://us02web.zoom.us/j/123456789?pwd=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

... like this:

```
zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=123456789&pwd=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If you have the Zoom app/client installed on a Mac, using URLs with the `zoommtg` protocol should cause them to open directly in the Zoom app, no matter where the URL is clicked from. Personally, I use this URL format in the Notes field of Calendar events, and it works great.

Comment: Hm, I can't quite get the integrated link password to work. The client always prompts from the passcode.

Comment: Are you manually updating the URL each time?

Comment: If it's a new meeting with a different URL, then yeah, I'd have to manually edit that URL to change it to the zoommtg:// format. But generally the meetings I do on Zoom are scheduled, so I only have to edit it once, then I add it to a calendar event and set it to repeat daily/weekly. I never touch it again.

Comment: This feature is now deprecated: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/client-url-schemes :(

Comment: Well, bummers. Everytime I need to enter my uni. programme's Zoom room, I have to open my university's Intranet and navigate 3–4 pages to find the link and pressing it, leads to another page asking if I want to open Zoom ... just a pain in the butt. Now when URL scheme is gone, what to do? I wish I could save the current room in Zoom for later.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson that link is now 404 and I couldn't find an alternative statement from Zoom...

Comment: I've removed Accepted status from this answer since the protocol was deprecated (and thank you for updating us) and since there are some promising alternatives with an extension and a possible change in Safari 17.

Answer (score 3):

Various extensions for the browser and chatbots allow you to open Zoom links directly:

- Alpaca https://alpaca.yahht.com
- ZoomIn https://github.com/soffes/ZoomIn

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Alpaca only works if the URL is shared inside of *Slack* or *MS Teams*; the OP wants to know about **Safari**.

Comment: ZoomIn is currently maintained here: https://github.com/ocastx/ZoomIn

Answer (score 3):

Safari 17, available now in beta includes an "Always Allow" option. After the first prompt, it will automatically open those links without waiting for user input.

[image: Safari 17 Prompt with "Always Allow" option]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be disabled...but...if the application you want to use is already running (or is in the dock), you can drag and drop the link onto the application's dock icon to avoid the dialog.

I just did it with a magnet link and Transmission and it did not invoke the dialog (I know, at the cost of a drag...which is...a drag).

Comment: Great idea (and nice pun), but dragging a link onto the application icon doesn't work with Zoom.us.